# Replace values with NA or 0 in one or multiple columns in dataframe conditionally based on values in another column

Tags: r

I am looking to replace values in one or multiple columns with NA or 0, conditionally based on values in another column. If the p-value is greater than or equal to 0.05 I want to replace the values in the first columns with NA or 0 and then show how to accomplish this for all three columns. DF is pictured below...

```
 R2       B1      X3  Species  pval
0.97    -0.68   -0.33   Sp1    0.004
-0.04   0.01    -0.41   Sp2    0.179
0.07    0.15    0.33    Sp3    0.227
-0.06   0.16    -1.05   Sp4    0.05
0.58    -0.29   -0.39   Sp5    0.001
0.13    0.53    0.47    Sp6    0.245
-0.04   -0.27   0.12    Sp7    0.597
-0.59   0.34    -0.19   Sp8    0.052
```

The dput structure is below...

```
structure(list(R2 = c(0.97, -0.04, 0.07, -0.06, 0.58, 0.13, -0.04, 
-0.59), B1 = c(-0.68, 0.01, 0.15, 0.16, -0.29, 0.53, -0.27, 0.34
), X3 = c(-0.33, -0.41, 0.33, -1.05, -0.39, 0.47, 0.12, -0.19
), Species = c("Sp1", "Sp2", "Sp3", "Sp4", "Sp5", "Sp6", "Sp7", 
"Sp8"), pval = c(0.004, 0.179, 0.227, 0.05, 0.001, 0.245, 0.597, 
0.052)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: `d` being your dataframe, you can use package *dplyr* and do the following to change, e. g., columns 1-3 as desired: `d |>  mutate(across(1:3, ~ ifelse(pval > .05, .x, NA)))`

Answer (score 3):

`d` being your dataframe, you can use package dplyr and do the following to change, e. g., columns 1-3 as desired:

```
d |>  mutate(across(1:3, ~ ifelse(pval > .05, .x, NA)))
```

on a related note: to create a variable with the first non-`NA` value per row, you can use `coalesce`, also of {dplyr}

Comment: I deleted my answer because your answer is more streamlined.

Comment: didn't mean to :-)

Comment: I edited the question to be greater than instead of less than. Tried to edit your answer accordingly but am unable to. Please adjust. However, I am unable to replace with 0 instead of NA. Is there a way to accomplish this? @I_O

Comment: @ecology this is all you need to change from the answer above:

Comment: d |>  mutate(across(1:3, ~ ifelse(pval < .05, .x, 0)))

Comment: There are only two changes that need to be made to I_O's answer to reflect your edit